# got unexpected result in post data using ajax

Tags: django, ajax

when I post data to the database using ajax code I got an unexpected result. I can post data but output showing is wrong. My ajax code not execute properly

**views.py**

```
def notification(request):
 user = request.user 
 if request.method == 'POST':

  property_id = request.POST['property_id'] 
  owner = request.POST['owner_id']
  property_object = Property.objects.get(id=property_id)
  owner_object =User.objects.all().get(username=owner)
  notification = "Hi {}, {} \n have interested 
     in your property '{}'".format(property_object.owner, user.first_name, property_object.headline) 
  property_object.notify.add(user)
  notifications = Notifications.objects.create(notification=notification, property=property_object, owner=owner_object)

  notifications.save()

  return JsonResponse({"msg":"success"})
```

**ajax code**

```
<form action="{% url 'notification' %}" method="post" id="notify_form" >
                {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="owner_id" value="{{ accomodation.owner }}">
            <button type="buttonsn" id="request-btn" name="property_id" value="{{ accomodation.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Contact info:</button>
            </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
$(document).on('submit','#request-btn',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var property_id = $this.attr('value');
    var owner_id = $this.attr('value');

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"{% url 'notification' %}",
        data:$('#notify_form').serialize(),
        dataType:'Json',
        success:function(data){
            if(data.msg == "success"){
                alert('data submitted')
            }
        }

    });
 });
});
```

I'm expecting a success alert box, but got

```
{"msg": "success"}
```

in a white window like 'httpResponse'. ajax code doesn't work

for overcome i'am try somechanges in mycode
i removed action address from form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="notify_form" >
```

but it doesn't work this time form not submitted
what can I do

Comment: What "white window"?  Do you mean that the page is posting the form and *navigating* to the result, rather than using AJAX?

Comment: question is updated now

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching the event handler to the button:

```
$(document).on('submit','#request-btn',function(e){
```

But buttons don't have submit events, forms do.  You can attach it to the form:

```
$(document).on('submit','#notify_form',function(e){
```

**Or** use the button's click event instead:

```
$(document).on('click','#request-btn',function(e){
```

Note also that there's a typo in the `type` attribute for the `<button>` element.  It should be:

```
type="button"
```